# Appending draggable into droppable container appends to wrong container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

There are many questions regarding draggable and droppable, but the titles are not that self-explanatory, and after checking around 20 questions, I decided to publish my problem here. I hope it's no exact duplicate...

**The idea** is to have a "grid" of droppables (`.time-slot`), similiar to a calendar, where every hour is a droppable. One can put multiple draggables (`.allocation`) on those droppables. When a draggable is dropped on a droppable, the draggable gets appended to the droppable, and repositioned to fit the top-left corner.

**This is working** as intended in the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/58Utc/

**The problem** is: if you change the height of the draggable to 300% or more, the draggable gets mostly appended to the wrong element and is off by one.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if it fits your needs, setting `tolerance` option of droppable to `pointer`:

```
tolerance: 'pointer',
```

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58Utc/2/)

Comment: Wow, thanks, that was fast! Together with `cursorAt` for the draggable, this works intuitive.